# Testing Amazon Quicksight Implementation

Tags: testing, python-behave, amazon-quicksight

My organisation are looking to move to Amazon Quicksight to replace our existing reporting solution. As part of the review before we move I have been asked to investigate the options for creating automated tests for the Quicksight implementation, the key thing will be ensuring that the correct data is presented correctly in the dashboards, dashboards work across a variety of different browsers, and any calculations are accurate and consistent.

looking online I can't find much documentation about test approaches for Quicksight implementations, our current test framework is Py-Behave. Is there any documentation providing test examples anywhere online, ideally examples of behave testing.

If not then does Quicksight allow for easy automated testing, is it possible to directly test dashboards via selenium tests etc and can any "data models" be easily tested directly to ensure the correct calculations etc are being applied?